# Como dejar de enviar la canción?

Tags: nodejs

```
var http = require('http'); 
var fs = require('fs'); 
var path = 'sx.mp3'; 

var cancion = fs.statSync(path); 

http.createServer(function(request, response) { 

response.writeHead(200, { 
'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg', 
'Content-Length': cancion.size
}); 
fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(response);
}) 

.listen(2000);
```

Esto lo que hace es enviar a un HTML a travez del puerto 2000 una canción para ser reproducida y funciona perfectamente

```
<audio src="http://ip:2000" controls autoplay loop hidden> 
<p>Tu navegador no soporta el elemento audio.</p> 
</audio
```

Mi problema es, cual es el método para dejar de enviar la canción al cliente y que este deje de reproducirla?

Y mi segundo problema es que debo cliquear el boton play del html para que reproduzca el audio, aunque esté en autoplay el , que debo hacer?

Comment: 1. Con un condicional: debes hacer streaming siempre y cuando se cumpla una determinada condición. 2. En algunos navegadores móviles el autoplay no se ejecuta. En estos casos necesitas empezar la reproducción por JavaScript (una línea de code).